# dotless.comple.exe. Why does it stop? what im i doing wrong? Or suggest me and alternative approach

Tags: visual-studio, less, nuget

Im trying to compile my `less` file to `css`, im using the `dotless`

I installed it with the `nuget`. This is the settings I got setup in project "Pre-build event command line"

```
“$(SolutionDir)packages\dotless.1.3.1.0\tool\dotless.compiler.exe” 
“$(ProjectDir)Content\style.less” 
“$(ProjectDir)Content\style_less.css”
```

What happends on build is that it just opens the `style.less` file in notepad and just stops there. When i close the `less` file, it opens the output `css` (empty) and same story here it just stops, when i close the `css` it does the regular build.

Ideas? is it supose to take time? is this behavior normal?

**EDIT**

Is there any other approach to compile LESS in Windows environment?

Comment: Maybe isn't what you're looking for... But you'll find a better experience compiling LESS using official JavaScript compiler. In my case, I got it to work using Windows Script Host and I've integrated this into the build process too.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer care to share your solution?

Comment: @DejanS Let me check if it's easy to share in a way that I can explain you it in a easy how-to...

Comment: @DejanS Check my answer. This worked for me, I'm using in some projects and works like a charm! ;)

Comment: @DejanS I've edited your question and I've added that you're open to learn other approaches than using DotLess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Less.net manually in my project and this is in my Pre-Build event:

```
If "$(ConfigurationName)" == Debug (
FOR %%i IN ("$(ProjectDir)css\*.less") DO ("$(ProjectDir)Tools\dotless.Compiler.exe" "%%i" )
) Else (
FOR %%i IN ("$(ProjectDir)css\*.less") DO ("$(ProjectDir)Tools\dotless.Compiler.exe" -m "%%i" )
)
```

This code will look in the css folder and transform all .less files to css files, when the project is in debug mode the css will be readable otherwise it's compressed. Don't forget to change the paths so it works in your environment. If there is an error in your .less file the error and line number will be shown in the Output window.

Comment: @Dejan.S I'd like to point that you requested me sharing my solution and you said nothing about it. If I was giving you other choice is because using official LESS compiler will always work better as it has the latest improvements, while using DotLess means that DotLess should be always sync'd with the official implementation of LESS. But it's up to you, I hope my answer will be useful for other people.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Actually, DotLess has fixed some bugs that are still in the official LESS compiler.

Comment: @ZippyV I prefer to stay away of unofficial implementations if there's one that works! But it's up to you and the OP.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer thanks for the solution, +1, its good and I'm sure people gone find it really useful (I'm gone try it out next project). The reason i haven commented its lack of time not on purpose. For me this was the solution to go with now because the ground work was done for it, just the pre-build script fix missing.

Comment: @Dejan.S Ok thanks! I said that because I had to adapt some things for you in order to make it shareable.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in some question comment, because DotLess didn't work for me, I switched to other approach: compiling LESS with official LESS compiler (JavaScript one) and executed using Windows Script Host.

Create a folder inside your solution directory *(i.e. where your **.sln** and project directories are stored for your particular solution).* Call your folder as **Build**.

You need these scripts (create a file for each one inside **Build** folder, I'm giving you the whole file name):

**lessc.wsf**

```
<!--
Less.js compiler for Windows Script Host
http://blog.dotsmart.net/

Copyright (c) 2010, Duncan Smart
Licensed under the Apache 2.0 License.
-->
<job>
<script language="jscript">
     // Stub out globals
    var window = this;
    var location = window.location = { 
        port: 0,
        href: ''
    };
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var input = null;

    var util = {
        readText: function (filename) {
            //WScript.StdErr.WriteLine("readText: " + filename);
            var file = fso.OpenTextFile(filename);
            // Don't error on empty files
            var text = file.AtEndOfStream ? '' : file.ReadAll();

            // Strip off any UTF-8 BOM
            var utf8bom = String.fromCharCode(0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF);
            if (text.substr(0, utf8bom.length) == utf8bom) {
                text = text.substr(utf8bom.length);
            }
            file.Close();
            return text;
        }
    };

    // XMLHttpRequest that just gets local files. Used when processing "@import"
    function XMLHttpRequest(){}
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype = {
        open: function (method, url, async) {
            this.url = url;
        },
        send: function () {
            // get the file path relative to the input less file/directory
            var currDir = fso.folderExists(input) ? input : fso.getParentFolderName(input);
            var filename = fso.BuildPath(currDir, this.url);

            //WScript.StdErr.WriteLine("XHR.send " + filename);

            // Little hack so *.less will resolve to *.less.css also. Helps with Visual Studio 
            // ensuring that file BuildAction is set to Content and you get rudimentary syntax highlighting with no set up.
            if (filename.match(/.less$/i) && !fso.FileExists(filename)) {
                filename = filename.replace(/.less$/i, '.less.css');
            }

            try {
                this.status = 200;
                this.responseText = util.readText(filename);
            }
            catch (e) {
                this.status = 404;
                this.responseText = e.description;
            }
        },
        setRequestHeader:  function () {},
        getResponseHeader: function () {}
    };

    // Fake document
    var document = {
        _dummyElement: {
            childNodes: [], 
            appendChild: function(){},
            style: {}
        },
        getElementsByTagName: function(){ return []; },
        getElementById: function(){ return this._dummyElement; },
        createElement:  function(){ return this._dummyElement; },
        createTextNode: function(){ return this._dummyElement; }
    };        

</script>

<!-- less.js from https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/tree/master/dist/ -->
<script language="jscript" src="less.js" />

<script language="jscript"> 
    // Parse args
    var args = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < WScript.Arguments.Length; i++) {
        var arg = WScript.Arguments.Item(i);
        // Handle "-switch" and "--switch"
        var match = arg.match(/^--?([a-z][0-9a-z-]*)$/i);
        if (match) {
            i = match[1];
            arg = true;
        }
        args[i] = arg;
    }

    input = args[0];
    var output = args[1];

    if (fso.folderExists(input)) {
        input = fso.getAbsolutePathName(input);
        var files = getFiles(input, /\.less$/i);
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            convert(file.path, output + '\\' + file.name.replace( /\.less$/i, '.css'));
        }
    }
    else {
        if (fso.folderexists(output)) {
            output = fso.getAbsolutePathName(output) + '\\' + fso.getfile(input).name.replace(/\.less$/i, '.css');
        }
        convert(input, output);
    }

    // Returns array of {name:'foo.bar', path:'c:\baz\foo.bar'} for given directory and pattern
    function getFiles(dir, regex) {
        var e = new Enumerator(fso.getFolder(dir).files);
        var files = []
        for (; !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext()) {
            if (regex.test(e.item().path)) {
                files.push({
                    name: e.item().name, 
                    path: e.item().path
                });
            }
        }
        return files;
    }

    function convert(input, output) {
        if (!input) {
            WScript.StdErr.WriteLine("lessc.wsf: no input files");
            WScript.StdErr.WriteLine("Usage:");
            WScript.StdErr.WriteLine("  Single file: cscript //nologo lessc.wsf input.less [output.css] [-compress]");
            WScript.StdErr.WriteLine("  Directory:   cscript //nologo lessc.wsf inputdir outputdir [-compress]");
            WScript.Quit(1);
        }

        var data;
        if (input == '-') {
            var chunks = [];
            while (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream)
            chunks.push(WScript.StdIn.ReadAll());
            data = chunks.join('');
        }
        else {
            data = util.readText(input);
        }

        var parser = new less.Parser({
            filename: input
        });

        try {
            parser.parse(data, function (err, tree) {

                if (err) {
                    WScript.StdErr.WriteLine("ERR: ");
                    for (var i in err) {
                        if (err[i]) {
                            WScript.StdErr.WriteLine("  " + i + ': ' + err[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    WScript.Quit(2);
                }
                else {
                    var css = tree.toCSS({
                        compress: args.compress
                    });
                    if (output) {
                        if(fso.FileExists(output))
                    {
                       var checkfile = fso.GetFile(output);
                       if(checkfile.Attributes & 1)
                       {
                           checkfile.Attributes = checkfile.Attributes ^ 1
                       }
                    }
                        var outputfile = fso.CreateTextFile(output);
                        outputfile.Write(css);
                        outputfile.Close();
                    }
                    else {
                        WScript.StdOut.Write(css);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            WScript.StdErr.WriteLine("ERROR:");
            for (var i in e) {
                if (e[i]) {
                    WScript.StdErr.WriteLine("  " + i + ': ' + e[i]);
                }
            }
            WScript.Quit(3);
        }

        // Sometimes less will return errors inside the fake HTML element
        if (document._dummyElement.innerHTML && document._dummyElement.innerHTML.match(/Syntax Error/i)) {
            var s = document._dummyElement.innerHTML;
            s = s.replace(/<[^>]+(\/?)>/g, function (m) { return m.indexOf('/') > 0 && m !== '</label>' ? "\n" : '' });
            s = s.replace(/\n+/g, '\n');

            WScript.StdErr.WriteLine("ERR: ");
            WScript.StdErr.WriteLine(s);
            WScript.Quit(2);
        }
    }
</script>
</job>
```

**lessc.cmd**

```
::For convenience
@cscript //nologo "%~dp0lessc.wsf" %*
```

**less.targets**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
  <DotLessCompilerPath>$(SolutionDir)Build\lessc.cmd</DotLessCompilerPath>
</PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="AllLessToCss" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <CreateItem Include="$(ProjectDir)**\*.less">
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="LessFile" />
    </CreateItem>

    <Message Text="" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="Now compiling LESS files..." Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="------------------------------------------------------------" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="File: &quot;%(LessFile.FullPath) ======>>>>> &quot;%(LessFile.RootDir)%(LessFile.Directory)%(LessFile.FileName).css&quot;" Importance="high" />

    <Exec Command="&quot;$(DotLessCompilerPath)&quot; &quot;%(LessFile.FullPath)&quot; &quot;%(LessFile.RootDir)%(LessFile.Directory)%(LessFile.FileName).css&quot; -compress"  />

    <Message Text="" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="------------------------------------------------------------" Importance="high" />
    <Message Text="" Importance="high" />
  </Target>
</project>
```

Once you've created the whole files inside **Build** folder, you need to modify your ASP.NET application project file (i.e. **.csproj**). In order to modify project file, you need to unload your project in Visual Studio IDE *(right-click on project node in your Solution Explorer and choose "Unload Project")*.

Now right-click again on unloaded project and choose "Edit project file". Go at the end of project file and just before `</project>` add the following XML code:

```
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)Build\less.targets" />
```

Finally, reload your ASP.NET project in Visual Studio, build it and, if everything went fine, you'll find a ".css" counterpart for any of your ASP.NET project LESS (.less) files!