# grunt less task fails silently when not using grunt-cli

Tags: gruntjs

I am at a loss as to why the less task fails silently. If I run it using grunt-cli and Gruntfile.js it works fine, but when I try to port it into another script the less task does not generate any output. Any help or insight as to why would be greatly appreciated.

```
'use strict';

var grunt = require('grunt'),
    _ = require('underscore'),
    path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    dir = require('node-dir');

var cssSrc = [];
var cssPaths = [];
var templates = [];
dir.paths('repo', function (err, paths) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    _.each(paths.files, function (file) {
        if (path.extname(file) === '.less') {
            cssSrc.push(file);
        }
    });
    cssPaths = paths.dirs;

    grunt.task.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.initConfig({
        less: {
            options: {
                paths: cssPaths
            },
            files: {
                'tmp/target.css': cssSrc
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.task.run('less');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies implicit to `grunt-cli`:

- nopt
- findup-sync
- resolve

are not explicitly included in a standalone script.

The `Gruntfile.js` script contains the path information:

- `repo` paths found using the `dir.paths` callback
- `tmp/target.css` paths found using `_.each`
- .less source paths found using `paths.dirs`

and uses the dependencies to do pathfinding.

There are unrelated questions about running less via [Rhino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961790/1113772#22149049) and [wsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341960/1113772#13342461) which explain the parameters for doing path finding explicitly.

**References**

- [npm: less](https://www.npmjs.org/package/less)
- [npm: grunt-cli](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-cli)
- [npm scripts man page](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html)
- [grunt-cli source](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-cli/blob/master/bin/grunt)
- [less: Third Party Compilers](https://github.com/less/less-docs/blob/master/content/usage/third-party-compilers.md)