# How to correctly execute lessc-rhino-1.6.3.js from command line

Tags: javascript, less, rhino

I'm trying "latest and greatest" LESS version and it seems it does not work in rhino command-line version. I've done following

1. Took latest rhino from here https://github.com/downloads/mozilla/rhino/rhino1_7R4.zip
2. Took latest less-rhino-1.6.3.js from here https://github.com/less/less.js/tree/master/dist
3. Running following from command line

   `java -jar js.jar less-rhino-1.6.3.js text.less text.css`

   or
   `java -jar js.jar less-rhino-1.6.3.js lessc-rhino-1.6.3.js text.less text.css`

The result is - "silently nothing".
When trying to run 'previous latest version' - it runs OK without problems

`java -jar js.jar less-rhino-1.5.1.js text.less text.css`

Output is

`Written to text.css`

What I'm missing about latest less-rhino.js? I could not find any relevant help in http://lesscss.org or https://github.com/less/less.js. The later jut says "stackoverflow.com is a great place to get answers about Less."

Comment: Quick question I need less-rhino too but I can't find the file anywhere. Could you please provide me with a link. The file doesn't seem to exist in the git repo at all anymore.

Comment: It appears that 1.7.5 is the last release with that file (Sep 3, 2014)
https://github.com/less/less.js/tree/v1.7.5/dist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found out how to do it in a nice way. Rhino has a `-f` flag which makes it simple to do .

```
java -jar js.jar -f less-rhino-1.6.3.js lessc-rhino-1.6.3.js text.less text.css
```

The above snippet should do the work for you. The 1.6.2 release of Less split the cli-stuff from Less into `lessc-rhino-[v].js` and the actual library into `less-rhino-[v].js`. It seems like this is an undocumented change unfortunately.